# regex alloy concentration with python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get element name and digits as regex's group. Even for the simplest case, like as shown, I cant:

```
>>> import re
>>> t = "Fe35C65"
>>> m = re.match("(\D*\d+\D*\d+)", t)
>>> print(m.group(1))
Fe35C65
>>> print(m.group(0))
Fe35C65
>>> print(m)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='Fe35C65'>
>>>
```

What I am looking is the output as

```
Name[0] = "Fe" Name[1]="C"
Num[0] = 35, Num[1] = 65
```

Here, there is 2 set, but it should not be limited. But, original problem is extractinh the data.

Comment: Why not use `re.findall(r'(\D*)(\d+)', t)`?

Comment: Hi, thanks.
Can you post this ans as reply? so that i can accept it?

Comment: Sorry, I was not sure this will work for you, as in such cases there are other things to take care, like validating the string at first.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: This is rudimentary example, and may be I need to parse and group things like, "(Fe35C65)25Co75", but thats a different question. I need validating the value, but that is after parsing it.

Comment: I added another solution for both validating and extracting with PyPi regex module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `re.match` only returns 1 match and the number of capturing groups is *fixed*.

To match multiple occurrences of your pattern you may use `re.findall` and the `r'(\D*)(\d+)'` pattern that matches and captures 0+ non-digit symbols onto Group 1 and then 1+ digits into Group 2:

```
re.findall(r'(\D*)(\d+)', t)
```

Since `re.findall` returns captured texts only, you will get a list of 2-element tuples.

#### Alternative solution with PyPi regex module

You may both *validate* a string and easily *capture* all occurrences of the multiple pairs of groups with the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) like this:

```
>>> import regex
>>> t = "Fe35C65"
>>> pat = r"(?:(\D*)(\d+))+"
>>> m = regex.fullmatch(pat, t)
>>> if m:
    print(zip(m.captures(1), m.captures(2)))
[('Fe', '35'), ('C', '65')]
```

The point here is:

- `(?:(\D*)(\d+))+` matches 1+ occurrences of (Group 1) 0+ non-digits and (Group 2) 1+ digits (*extraction*)
- `regex.fullmatch` requires the entire string to match the pattern (*validation*)
- The captures are stored in a group capture stack and can be accessed with `.captures(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

If there can be many you can use this:

```
x="Fe35C65"
m=re.compile(r"(\D+)(\d+)")
for i in m.finditer(x):
    print i.groups()
```

Output:

```
('Fe', '35')
('C', '65')
```